# Sort array in ascending order while eleminating repeated values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on project where I have array simmilar to this

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width768px', 'width959px', 'width767px', 'width767px' ];
```

I want to sort this array in ascending order while eleminating repeated values so that result should be

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width767px', 'width768px', 'width959px' ];
```

I'm using following function to sort array in ascending array but how do I eliminate immediate values ?? (In above case **'width767px'**)

```
var sortBp = bpArrays.sort(function(a, b) {
                    a = a.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
                    b = b.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
                    return a - b;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It !!

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width768px', 'width959px', 'width767px', 'width767px' ];

uniqueArray = sortBp.filter(function(elem, pos) {
        return sortBp.indexOf(elem) == pos;
});
```

EDIT :

I have found another solution here : http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/eliminating-duplicates/

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
      var i, len=arr.length, out=[], obj={};
      for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
      }
      for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
      }
      return out;
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient, will take `O(n^2)` time. Of course it's fine with your 6 elements example, but still I suggest plain loop-compare solution. (since you already sorted the array, it will take `O(n)` time only.)

Comment: can you give me example ? I'm new to javascript.

Comment: I added answer, please see that one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't eliminate elements while sorting. You have to sort the array first, then remove duplicates. Your solution using `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.indexOf` might be good for unsorted array, but since your array is sorted, it's overhead here(takes `O(n)` for each). Instead you can just loop through the array and compare element with previous one.

```
function uniq(array) {
  var i, l = array.length, result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (result[result.length - 1] != array[i]) {
      result.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This is same with [Underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L454) and [Prototype](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/array.js#L325)'s uniq() implemention.

Last note: remember that this will work fine with sorted array only.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not homework, i.e. you aren't required to implement the algorithm yourself, you could use a combination of [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) and [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) functions.

```
sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width768px', 'width959px', 'width767px', 'width767px' ];
_.uniq(_.sortBy(sortBp, function(x) {return x;}), true);
```

This returns:

```
["height58em", "width480px", "width767px", "width768px", "width959px"]
```

Note that this will be sort by lexical order, and if you do not wish this to happen, simply substitute the identity function `function(x) {return x;}` with your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(k) {
for ( var p in this)
if (this[p] === k)
  return true;
return false;
};




inputArray.sort();

function uniqueArray(inputArray){
result=[];
for(var i in inputArray){
if(!result.contains(inputArray[i])){
result.push(inputArray[i]);
}
}
return result;
}
```